# Uncaught ReferenceError for Image rotation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

We gave an option for user to Upload the images inside mask images, Also we are   displaying rotate button on top.... Once user upload image , onclick rotate button, its rotating the uploaded image as in [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uf4h6x08/) , here is [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1x4xstdkOz25fcRXUvy9s7HYT-_HTeErh/view)

**Issue** :

I integrated rotation code in our project , its giving below error :

`Uncaught ReferenceError: mask is not defined`

**Steps to Reproduce** :

1.Click on Mask image.

2.Upload Image

3.Click on Rotate button

Below is **Code Snippet** :

```js
var target;
const imageUrl = "https://i.imgur.com/RzEm1WK.png";

let jsonData = {
    "layers": [{
        "x": 0,
        "height": 612,
        "layers": [{
                "x": 160,
                "src": "ax0HVTs.png",
                "y": 291,
                "height": 296,
                "width": 429,
                "name": "mask_1"
            },
            {
                "x": 25,
                "src": "hEM2kEP.png",
                "height": 324,
                "width": 471,
                "y": 22,
                "name": "mask_2"
            }
        ],
        "y": 0,
        "width": 612
    }]
};

const containerElement = $('#container');
const fileUp = $('#fileup');

$(function() {

    // Upload image onclick mask image 

    containerElement.click(function(e) {
        var res = e.target;
        target = res.id;
        console.log(target);
        if (e.target.getContext) {
            // click only inside Non Transparent part
            var pixel = e.target.getContext('2d').getImageData(e.offsetX, e.offsetY, 1, 1).data;
            if (pixel[3] === 255) {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    $('#fileup').click();
                }, 20);
            }
        }
    });

    // Fetch mask images from json file - IGNORE this code

    function getAllSrc(layers) {
        let arr = [];
        layers.forEach(layer => {
            if (layer.src) {
                arr.push({
                    src: layer.src,
                    x: layer.x,
                    y: layer.y,
                    height: layer.height,
                    width: layer.width,
                    name: layer.name
                });
            } else if (layer.layers) {
                let newArr = getAllSrc(layer.layers);
                if (newArr.length > 0) {
                    newArr.forEach(({
                        src,
                        x,
                        y,
                        height,
                        width,
                        name
                    }) => {
                        arr.push({
                            src,
                            x: (layer.x + x),
                            y: (layer.y + y),
                            height,
                            width,
                            name: (name)
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        return arr;
    }

    function json(data)

    {
        var width = 0;
        var height = 0;

        let arr = getAllSrc(data.layers);

        let layer1 = data.layers;
        width = layer1[0].width;
        height = layer1[0].height;
        let counter = 0;
        let table = [];

        // container dimensions
        containerElement.css('width', width + "px").css('height', height + "px").addClass('temp');
        //end

        for (let {
                src,
                x,
                y,
                name
            } of arr) {

            //Get Height and width of mask image [ edit button ]
            var ImagePosition = arr;
            //code end

            var mask = $(".container").mask({
                imageUrl: imageUrl,

                // Fetch Mask images
                maskImageUrl: 'https://i.imgur.com/' + src,
                // end

                onMaskImageCreate: function(img) {
                    // Mask image positions
                    img.css({
                        "position": "absolute",
                        "left": x + "px",
                        "top": y + "px"
                    });
                    // end

                },
                id: counter
            });
            table.push(mask);
            fileup.onchange = function() {

                let mask2 = table[target];
                const newImageLoadedId = mask2.loadImage(URL.createObjectURL(fileup.files[0]));
                document.getElementById('fileup').value = "";


            };
            counter++;
        }
    }
    json(jsonData);

    // Rotate code: 

    let imageToSpin = document.getElementById('self');
    var r = 0;

    function spinImage() {
        r += 10;
        mask.rotate(r);
    }
    btnTotate.onclick = spinImage;

}); // end of function

// Image code

(function($) {
    var JQmasks = [];
    $.fn.mask = function(options) {
        // This is the easiest way to have default options.
        var settings = $.extend({
            // These are the defaults.
            maskImageUrl: undefined,
            imageUrl: undefined,
            scale: 1,
            id: new Date().getUTCMilliseconds().toString(),
            x: 0, // image start position
            y: 0, // image start position
            onMaskImageCreate: function(div) {},
            rotate: 0, // rotation
        }, options);


        var container = $(this);

        let prevX = 0,
            prevY = 0,
            draggable = false,
            img,
            canvas,
            context,
            image,
            timeout,
            initImage = false,
            startX = settings.x,
            startY = settings.y,
            rotate = settings.rotate,
            div;


        container.mousePosition = function(event) {
            return {
                x: event.pageX || event.offsetX,
                y: event.pageY || event.offsetY
            };
        }

        container.selected = function(ev) {
            var pos = container.mousePosition(ev);
            var item = $(".masked-img canvas").filter(function() {
                var offset = $(this).offset()
                var x = pos.x - offset.left;
                var y = pos.y - offset.top;
                var d = this.getContext('2d').getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
                return d[0] > 0
            });

            JQmasks.forEach(function(el) {
                var id = item.length > 0 ? $(item).attr("id") : "";
                if (el.id == id)
                    el.item.enable();
                else el.item.disable();
            });
        };

        container.enable = function() {
            draggable = true;
            $(canvas).attr("active", "true");
            div.css({
                "z-index": 2
            });
        }

        container.disable = function() {
            draggable = false;
            $(canvas).attr("active", "false");
            div.css({
                "z-index": 1
            });
        }

        container.getImagePosition = function() {
            return {
                x: settings.x,
                y: settings.y,
                scale: settings.scale
            };
        };

        container.updateStyle = function() {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                context.beginPath();
                context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
                image = new Image();
                image.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
                image.src = settings.maskImageUrl;
                image.onload = function() {
                    canvas.width = image.width;
                    canvas.height = image.height;
                    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);
                    div.css({
                        "width": image.width,
                        "height": image.height
                    });
                    context.save();
                    context.rotate(rotate);
                    resolve();
                };
            });
        };

        function renderInnerImage() {
            img = new Image();
            img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
            img.src = settings.imageUrl;
            img.onload = function() {
                settings.x = settings.x == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.width - (img.width * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.x;
                settings.y = settings.y == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.height - (img.height * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.y;
                context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';
                context.drawImage(img, settings.x, settings.y, img.width * settings.scale, img.height * settings.scale);
                context.restore();
                initImage = false;

            };
        }

        container.rotate = function(r) {
            rotate = r;
            container.updateStyle();
        }


        // change the draggable image

        container.loadImage = function(imageUrl) {
            console.log("load");
            settings.y = startY;
            settings.x = startX;
            prevX = prevY = 0;
            settings.imageUrl = imageUrl;
            initImage = true;
            container.updateStyle().then(renderInnerImage);
            // sirpepole  Add this
            return settings.id;
        };

        container.loadMaskImage = function(imageUrl, from) {
            canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            canvas.setAttribute("draggable", "true");
            canvas.setAttribute("id", settings.id);
            settings.maskImageUrl = imageUrl;
            div = $("<div/>", {
                "class": "masked-img"
            }).append(canvas);

            // div.find("canvas").on('touchstart mousedown', function(event)
            div.find("canvas").on('dragstart', function(event) {
                if (event.handled === false) return;
                event.handled = true;
                container.onDragStart(event);
            });

            div.find("canvas").on('touchend mouseup', function(event) {
                if (event.handled === false) return;
                event.handled = true;
                container.selected(event);
            });

            div.find("canvas").bind("dragover", container.onDragOver);
            container.append(div);
            if (settings.onMaskImageCreate)
                settings.onMaskImageCreate(div);
            container.loadImage(settings.imageUrl);
        };
        container.loadMaskImage(settings.maskImageUrl);
        JQmasks.push({
            item: container,
            id: settings.id
        })
        // Edit image
        div.addClass('masked-img' + settings.id);
        // end
        return container;
    };
}(jQuery));
```

```css
.container {
 background: silver;
 position: relative;
 
}

.container img {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 250px;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 margin: auto;
 z-index: 999;
}

.masked-img {
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
}
.rotated 
{
  transform: rotate(90deg)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<input type="button" id="btnTotate" value="rotate"/>

<input id="fileup" name="fileup" type="file" style="display:none" >

<div id="container"class="container">
</div>
```

Here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kidsdial1/suzxgh81/) & [CodePen](https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/GagKwX)

Please let me know if you need more information....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var target,mask;
const imageUrl = "https://i.imgur.com/RzEm1WK.png";

let jsonData = {
    "layers": [{
        "x": 0,
        "height": 612,
        "layers": [{
                "x": 160,
                "src": "ax0HVTs.png",
                "y": 291,
                "height": 296,
                "width": 429,
                "name": "mask_1"
            },
            {
                "x": 25,
                "src": "hEM2kEP.png",
                "height": 324,
                "width": 471,
                "y": 22,
                "name": "mask_2"
            }
        ],
        "y": 0,
        "width": 612
    }]
};

const containerElement = $('#container');
const fileUp = $('#fileup');

$(function() {

    // Upload image onclick mask image 

    containerElement.click(function(e) {
        var res = e.target;
        target = res.id;
        console.log(target);
        if (e.target.getContext) {
            // click only inside Non Transparent part
            var pixel = e.target.getContext('2d').getImageData(e.offsetX, e.offsetY, 1, 1).data;
            if (pixel[3] === 255) {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    $('#fileup').click();
                }, 20);
            }
        }
    });

    // Fetch mask images from json file - IGNORE this code

    function getAllSrc(layers) {
        let arr = [];
        layers.forEach(layer => {
            if (layer.src) {
                arr.push({
                    src: layer.src,
                    x: layer.x,
                    y: layer.y,
                    height: layer.height,
                    width: layer.width,
                    name: layer.name
                });
            } else if (layer.layers) {
                let newArr = getAllSrc(layer.layers);
                if (newArr.length > 0) {
                    newArr.forEach(({
                        src,
                        x,
                        y,
                        height,
                        width,
                        name
                    }) => {
                        arr.push({
                            src,
                            x: (layer.x + x),
                            y: (layer.y + y),
                            height,
                            width,
                            name: (name)
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        return arr;
    }

    function json(data)

    {
        var width = 0;
        var height = 0;

        let arr = getAllSrc(data.layers);

        let layer1 = data.layers;
        width = layer1[0].width;
        height = layer1[0].height;
        let counter = 0;
        let table = [];

        // container dimensions
        containerElement.css('width', width + "px").css('height', height + "px").addClass('temp');
        //end

        for (let {
                src,
                x,
                y,
                name
            } of arr) {

            //Get Height and width of mask image [ edit button ]
            var ImagePosition = arr;
            //code end

             mask = $(".container").mask({
                imageUrl: imageUrl,

                // Fetch Mask images
                maskImageUrl: 'https://i.imgur.com/' + src,
                // end

                onMaskImageCreate: function(img) {
                    // Mask image positions
                    img.css({
                        "position": "absolute",
                        "left": x + "px",
                        "top": y + "px"
                    });
                    // end

                },
                id: counter
            });
            table.push(mask);
            fileup.onchange = function() {

                let mask2 = table[target];
                const newImageLoadedId = mask2.loadImage(URL.createObjectURL(fileup.files[0]));
                document.getElementById('fileup').value = "";


            };
            counter++;
        }
    }
    json(jsonData);

    // Rotate code: 

    let imageToSpin = document.getElementById('self');
    var r = 0;

    function spinImage() {
        r += 10;
        mask.rotate(r);
    }
    btnTotate.onclick = spinImage;

}); // end of function

// Image code

(function($) {
    var JQmasks = [];
    $.fn.mask = function(options) {
        // This is the easiest way to have default options.
        var settings = $.extend({
            // These are the defaults.
            maskImageUrl: undefined,
            imageUrl: undefined,
            scale: 1,
            id: new Date().getUTCMilliseconds().toString(),
            x: 0, // image start position
            y: 0, // image start position
            onMaskImageCreate: function(div) {},
            rotate: 0, // rotation
        }, options);


        var container = $(this);

        let prevX = 0,
            prevY = 0,
            draggable = false,
            img,
            canvas,
            context,
            image,
            timeout,
            initImage = false,
            startX = settings.x,
            startY = settings.y,
            rotate = settings.rotate,
            div;


        container.mousePosition = function(event) {
            return {
                x: event.pageX || event.offsetX,
                y: event.pageY || event.offsetY
            };
        }

        container.selected = function(ev) {
            var pos = container.mousePosition(ev);
            var item = $(".masked-img canvas").filter(function() {
                var offset = $(this).offset()
                var x = pos.x - offset.left;
                var y = pos.y - offset.top;
                var d = this.getContext('2d').getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
                return d[0] > 0
            });

            JQmasks.forEach(function(el) {
                var id = item.length > 0 ? $(item).attr("id") : "";
                if (el.id == id)
                    el.item.enable();
                else el.item.disable();
            });
        };

        container.enable = function() {
            draggable = true;
            $(canvas).attr("active", "true");
            div.css({
                "z-index": 2
            });
        }

        container.disable = function() {
            draggable = false;
            $(canvas).attr("active", "false");
            div.css({
                "z-index": 1
            });
        }

        container.getImagePosition = function() {
            return {
                x: settings.x,
                y: settings.y,
                scale: settings.scale
            };
        };

        container.updateStyle = function() {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                context.beginPath();
                context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
                image = new Image();
                image.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
                image.src = settings.maskImageUrl;
                image.onload = function() {
                    canvas.width = image.width;
                    canvas.height = image.height;
                    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);
                    div.css({
                        "width": image.width,
                        "height": image.height
                    });
                    context.save();
                    context.rotate(rotate);
                    resolve();
                };
            });
        };

        function renderInnerImage() {
            img = new Image();
            img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
            img.src = settings.imageUrl;
            img.onload = function() {
                settings.x = settings.x == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.width - (img.width * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.x;
                settings.y = settings.y == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.height - (img.height * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.y;
                context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';
                context.drawImage(img, settings.x, settings.y, img.width * settings.scale, img.height * settings.scale);
                context.restore();
                initImage = false;

            };
        }

        container.rotate = function(r) {
            rotate = r;
            container.updateStyle();
        }


        // change the draggable image

        container.loadImage = function(imageUrl) {
            console.log("load");
            settings.y = startY;
            settings.x = startX;
            prevX = prevY = 0;
            settings.imageUrl = imageUrl;
            initImage = true;
            container.updateStyle().then(renderInnerImage);
            // sirpepole  Add this
            return settings.id;
        };

        container.loadMaskImage = function(imageUrl, from) {
            canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            canvas.setAttribute("draggable", "true");
            canvas.setAttribute("id", settings.id);
            settings.maskImageUrl = imageUrl;
            div = $("<div/>", {
                "class": "masked-img"
            }).append(canvas);

            // div.find("canvas").on('touchstart mousedown', function(event)
            div.find("canvas").on('dragstart', function(event) {
                if (event.handled === false) return;
                event.handled = true;
                container.onDragStart(event);
            });

            div.find("canvas").on('touchend mouseup', function(event) {
                if (event.handled === false) return;
                event.handled = true;
                container.selected(event);
            });

            div.find("canvas").bind("dragover", container.onDragOver);
            container.append(div);
            if (settings.onMaskImageCreate)
                settings.onMaskImageCreate(div);
            container.loadImage(settings.imageUrl);
        };
        container.loadMaskImage(settings.maskImageUrl);
        JQmasks.push({
            item: container,
            id: settings.id
        })
        // Edit image
        div.addClass('masked-img' + settings.id);
        // end
        return container;
    };
}(jQuery));
```

```css
.container {
 background: silver;
 position: relative;
 
}

.container img {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 250px;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 margin: auto;
 z-index: 999;
}

.masked-img {
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
}
.rotated 
{
  transform: rotate(90deg)
}
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<input type="button" id="btnTotate" value="rotate"/>

<input id="fileup" name="fileup" type="file" style="display:none" >

<div id="container"class="container">
</div>
```

You must learn variable scoping. Your mask variable is inside the json function only.Either you can have it global or declare it outside of the function so it can be accessed by other functions.

Comment: thanks , there is no console errors now, but `rotate` functionality is not working once we upload image & click on `rotate` , can you please check once....

Comment: it's up for you to find out :) I only answered your question.